# Sorting comments and replies in different direction with SQL

Tags: mysql

I am having difficulties when trying to sort comments with three levels of hierarchy on my website.

I have a table 'comment' which contains either comments or answers to comments. These comments have a `cid`, unique identifier, a `pid`, that indicates the `cid` of a parent comment if the former comment is an answer to another comment, and a `thread` field.

This thread is built based on a specific pattern : "00/", "01/" etc are level 0 comments, "00.00/", "00.01" etc are replies to comment "00/" and so on.

I only want three levels of hierarchy, meaning that the `thread` won't be longer than "xx.xx.xx/"

I would like to sort the comments from newest to oldest, BUT sort the replies the other way round.

Simple example :

```
02/
02.01/
02.01.00/
02.02/
02.03/
02.03.00/
02.03.01/
01/
01.00/
00/
```

(Hope I made it clear enough for you to understand !)

The main point is that I am not really good at SQL queries, and I'd be delighted if you could help me with this one

So far I had a query that worked but only for level 0 and 1 comments :

```
SELECT  `cid` ,  `thread` 
FROM  `comment` 
ORDER BY SUBSTR(`thread`, 1, 2 ) DESC ,  `cid` ASC
```

And here's the result :

```
0z/
0z.00/
0z.01/
0z.00.00/
0z.00.01/
0z.01.00/
0z.01.01/
0y/
0x/
...
```

Do you have any ideas ? (please make it simple ... thanks !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need a second and third order condition:

```
SELECT  `cid` ,  `thread` 
FROM  `comment` 
ORDER BY SUBSTR(`thread`, 1, 2 ) DESC ,  SUBSTR(`thread`, 4, 2 ) ASC, SUBSTR(`thread`, 7, 2 ) ASC
```

which sorts the first part descending, the second parts inside of each first part ascending and the third parts inside of each second part ascending, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that just works perfectly. Didn't know I could add so many Orderby queries on the same field :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using three separate fields for threads and make each an int, or tinyint perhaps.  Let's call the fields ThreadLevel1, ThreadLevel2 and ThreadLevel3.   Otherwise as your table gets large the sort will take a long time.  Then you can do

```
select cid, concat(ThreadLevel1, ThreadLevel2, ThreadLevel3) 
from comment
order by ThreadLevel1 desc, ThreadLevel2 asc, ThreadLevel3 asc
```

You will also need to define and index. Most likely you can use an index on ThreadLevel1, but you may also benefit from a multiple-column index on (ThreadLevel1, ThreadLevel2, ThreadLevel3).  Since the first is descending and the rest is ascending I am not sure the multiple column will help in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works very well too. It might be a little bit cleaner than Smutje's query, but his answer fits perfectly what I wanted to do

Comment: Right, but as your table grows, you may see a performance issue.

Comment: Then I'll try your way, but the thing is that I'm supposed to change it into a Drupal query, and I'm not sure Drupal is supporting all this ..?

Comment: Do you have a large dataset to try it on?  Meaning like 1,000,000 records?

Comment: Actually there won't be more than 40 or 50 comments per article imo. I don't have such a dataset to handle (thankfully, I must say)

Comment: Then you probably don't need to use my suggestions.

Comment: Anyway it is always good to have multiple points of view and solutions. Thanks for your time :)